I can't configure Spring Cloud Gateway to validate some routes with OAuth2 and allow others to redirect without validation
I want to configure so that the route /api/v1/auth/** validates authentication with the token I send from a front with Angular. At the same time, I want requests to /api/v1/user/** not to require authentication and reroute without authentication. As I currently have it configured, it asks for authentication for both routes, so it doesn't work as I want. Moreover, if I send the token from Postman, it works correctly, but from Angular, I get a cors error.
In tha API Gateway console, I have this:
2024-04-03T12:20:59.008+02:00 DEBUG 4188 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-2] .s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter$DefaultRequireCsrfProtectionMatcher@39c0c881
2024-04-03T12:20:59.008+02:00 DEBUG 4188 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-2] .s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : Did not match
2024-04-03T12:20:59.013+02:00 DEBUG 4188 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/logout', method=POST}
2024-04-03T12:20:59.014+02:00 DEBUG 4188 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-1] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'OPTIONS /api/v1/user/1' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2024-04-03T12:20:59.014+02:00 DEBUG 4188 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : No matches found
2024-04-03T12:20:59.015+02:00 DEBUG 4188 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-1] a.DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on '/api/v1/user/1' using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager@7967ad6a
2024-04-03T12:20:59.016+02:00 DEBUG 4188 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-1] ebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@54f86865'
2024-04-03T12:20:59.016+02:00 DEBUG 4188 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthorizationWebFilter       : Authorization failed: Access Denied
2024-04-03T12:20:59.018+02:00 DEBUG 4188 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-1] ebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@54f86865'

In the browser's terminal, I have this:
Access to fetch at 'http***' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

API Gateway:
POM:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.vortex</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api-gateway</name>
    <description>The gateway for Vortex Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

application.yml:
#logs
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    org:
      springframework:
        cloud:
          gateway: DEBUG
        web:
          reactive: DEBUG
        reactor:
          netty: DEBUG
        oauth2:
          client: DEBUG

# API Gateway Configuration
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      # Routes Configuration
      routes:
        - id: auth-cognito
          uri: http://localhost:8083
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/auth/**
            - Method=POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS


        - id: user-service
          uri: http://localhost:8084
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/user/**
            - Method=POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS

#       Global Filters Configuration
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, RETAIN_UNIQUE

      # Global CORS Configuration
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods: "*"
            exposedHeaders: "*"


  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: cognito
          jwk-set-uri: cognito


angular:
HttpInterceptorFn:
import { HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CognitoService } from '../services/cognito.service';

export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {

     const cognitoService = inject(CognitoService);
     const token = cognitoService.token;

     const authReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
  
  return next(authReq);
};

appConfig:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    
    provideRouter(routes), 
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient(
      withInterceptors([authInterceptor]),
      withFetch(),
    )
  ]
};


You should not configure your Angular app as a public client (have it fetch tokens) and you should not remove security from the resource servers (this is unsafe and access control on the Gateway induces tight coupling with downstream resources). Instead, configure the Gateway as an OAuth2 BFF
